# Learn Python the Hard way ex25 - syntax error

Tags: python, python-2.7

Ive been going over this for a while and cant seem to find whats wrong with it as im getting a syntax error on line 13. I would love if someone could nudge me in the correct direction here because im starting to pull my hair out.

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break up words for us"""
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    """sorts the words"""
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(words):
    """prints the first word after popping it off"""
    word = words.pop(0)
    print word # line 13

def print_last_word(words):
    """prints the last word after popping it off"""
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print word

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    """Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    return sorted_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """Prints the first and last words in the sentence"""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    print_first)word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    """Sorts the words then prints the first and last one"""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
```

Error:

```
File "ex25.py", line 28
   print_first)word(words)
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Where is line 13? I don't have enough fingers =p

Comment: Please post the stack trace. It'd help to know what the error actually is...

Comment: are you sure about python2.7?

Comment: File "ex25.py", line 28
    print_first)word(words)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original version of your code didn't have line numbers and had this:

```
def print_last_word(words):
        """prints the last word after popping it off"""
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print word
```

which would lead to

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

But the others are right and the `print` was your first problem. You are running Python 3.x and need to use the `print` **function**.

The error at line 28 is an obvious typo.

Comment: Sorry this got all garbled when I copy/pasted here. I think the python3 issue is correct. Thanks... >< Both python3 and 2.7 are installed and I wasnt explicitly running 2.7.7

Comment: I can not see on the OP code the first problem you mention (indentation). And it was not the root of the problem described. Please edit because imho, currently, the answer is confusing (despite it was selected by the OP).

Comment: @joaquin Edited (I didn't notice that the OP fixed the indentation error in their code, thanks).

Comment: I was working on a laptop that wasnt mine and had a bad time trying to cut/paste into comments partially due to screen glare. There were no indent problems and that error that was even posted was incorrect. The actual problem was the version because I had not known that both 2.7 and 3.2 were installed on the machine, it was not something obvious to me but thanks for the help that was offered here.

Answer (score 2):

Since line 13 is a `print` statement, I'm assuming you're using python3. In python3, `print` is a function: `print(word)`. The next error will be about indentation...

Line 28 is a typo, `)` instead of `_`.

Answer (score 2):

Line 28...

```
28      print_first)word(words)
```

should be...

```
28      print_first_word(words)
```

(Note: right parenthesis where it should be an underscore.)